Ender 3 print head doesn't rise when printing
I'm stuck with this one and can't find an answer online, so here it is.
I've had an Ender 3 for coming up to two years now, it's generally been running fine, the occasional head clogging but nothing I can't fix. However, yesterday my teenager tried printing a test cube in PLA, and it appears the print head didn't rise for each layer, so it's indented into the flexible PEI plate and wrecked it. She's every bit as competent as I am with the printer, indeed uses it more than I do. The only possibly relevant upgrade is moving to a direct drive, which was done about nine months ago.
The only other change I've made recently was install a Creality CR Touch leveller, but haven't as yet updated the firmware due to lack of time, so left the leveller attached but not connected to the motherboard, e.g. put the printer back to it's original setup, reconnected the Z-stop etc. Besides, we've had several successful prints since then.
When you raise the Z axis through the control panel, it moves fine, so it doesn't appear to be a motor issue, and the test cube file has printed successfully several times in the past, so it doesn't appear to be a file issue either.
Any questions/suggestions to troubleshoot this issue would be graciously received.

Based on what you describe, I'd definitely suspect a failed Z-axis motor. But that's not it. Did this only happen once or does it also happen when you put a completely different print on? Your plate may seem ruined, but it's only ruined in that area. The rest is still usable for debugging the issue, make sure you move your next print off-center.

Have you tried to re-slice the test cube and print it?

Could it be your Z-stop has moved in height? You see nozzle drag marks to the brim, this implies that there is something wrong with the level. Trouble shoot the printer by sending commands to home and position the head. If that is correct or fixed, move on to slice a new cube, not the old G-code to be certain. If the printer moves okay, it should do so when printing, so the G-code file must be the problem.
